# Microsoft Cognitive Services Sentiment Analysis: Retention period

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We're seeking to use Microsoft Cognitive Services for Sentiment Analysis as part of an Azure subscription. We need to work out how long the Sentiment Analysis data will be retained for once it's uploaded. Ideally, we'd like to have the data deleted after the analysis result is returned or be able to configure the retention time ourselves.

Does anyone have documentation on how Cognitive Services handles uploaded data for Sentiment Analysis?

Looking through the [Online Services Terms](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/DocumentSearch.aspx?Mode=3&DocumentTypeId=31) I've found the following T&C:

> **Inactive Cognitive Services Configurations and Custom Models**
>
> For the purposes of data retention and deletion, a Cognitive Services configuration or custom model that has been inactive may at Microsoft’s discretion be treated as an Online Service... [etc]

We're not talking about an inactive service, but this is the only text under Cognitive Services referring data retention. The general Online Services rules also only talk about deletion at the end of contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis#step-2-post-the-request) that no data is stored in your account and that the results are returned immediately in the response, which I assume means that once you receive the results the data gets deleted.

Comment: Thank you for that document link. We've also gotten confirmation from Microsoft that no data is retained, but the documentation is invaluable.